# How to reduce TTFB time under rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Under development environment, my app sends GET request which is completed for 10 seconds (Completed 200 OK in 10000 ms ...., is written into console output). But TTFB time is about 40 seconds. GET request receives about 3 MB data.
I arranged response, so the processing is not change but response is empty array and nothing is change about times.
So who uses this time from 'controller finished job' to 'TTFB time, browser receives first byte'
Any explanation?